# unable to handle kernel null pointer dereference

Tags: c, oop, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I am getting the unable to handle kernel null pointer dereference error while using my kernel module.
Here is what I am trying to do

```
inputfile = filp_open(kernel_args->infile, O_RDONLY, 0); //Open a file

if(inputfile == NULL) //Check if the file exists
{
    printk("\nInput file not found on drive\n");
    error = -ENOENT;
    goto quit;
}
```

But the kernel gives me an "oops" when checking for null. I dont know how to avoid it since I am checking for null and doing what I am supposed to do.

Comment: That's all there is to `inputfile`?

Comment: Did you make check `kernel_args->infile` to make sure it's not NULL?

Comment: BEfore the about code, the only time inputfile is used, is for declaration 'struct file *inputfile = NULL;'

kernel_args->infile is not NULL

Comment: @haunteddevil619: What about references to `inputfile` **after** the call to `filp_open`?

Comment: @K-ballo no references after flip_open. The code is just as I posted

Comment: @haunteddevil619: Undefined behavior before or even after your null check could cause it to be optimized away, it has been known to happen before at the linux kernel itself... But if that's just it, then I don't see why it would fail

Comment: @K-ballo Surely there is code above the open statement, but it has nothing to do with 'inputfile'. I also just checked by giving a correct file name and the program ran smoothly without and "oops"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you suspected the wrong pointer, the only pointer that may generate such oops in your code is kernel_args.

few more tips:
- kernel is trusted code, you shouldn't check NULL pointers (unless you are writing kernel module test etc)
- your printk usage is wrong, you are missing the printk log level, for example: printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello world\n");

Answer (score 0):

Check the validity of kernel space arguments.

Like :

```
if (!kargs)
    if(kargs->infile == NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since filp_open will not return NULL while something went wrong, you should use IS_ERR to check error occurrence.

Like:

```
if(IS_ERR(inputfile))
    goto quit;
```